# Open source tool for Database Continuous integration

Tags: sql-server, database, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I want to perform Database continuous integration. I found that Red gate is the tool for Database CI using SQL CI.

> It allows continuous integration for SQL Server databases. On each check-in to source control, it builds and packages the database changes, alongside application code.
>
> It also validates the structure of database, runs unit tests with realistic test data, and checks that database changes can be deployed.

Is there any open source tool to do the same functionality as Red gate? I need some expert advice for this. So I am posting it. Is there any jenkins plugin or open source tool? Thanks.

Comment: Per the close reasons, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow "

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server Data Tools. It is not open source, but it is going with Visual Studion 2010+.

Comment: hi sidux. thanks for your reply. I will look at it. Any open source tool will help me lot.

Comment: I am not sure that you'll find something useable. I've spent on that quite a bit time and currently doing that on TFS + SSDT

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a look at DBmaestro (http://www2.dbmaestro.com/l/11742/2014-12-31/2grnfp), while it is not an open source tool it does provide continuous integration to the database. Continuous Integration to the database includes:

1. Enforced source control - any change to the database object is being documented using Check-Out/In, so you can modify your database workspace as you do to your C#, Java
2. Baseline aware analysis - generating delta SQL scripts by comparing A, B and C which identifies if a difference is a valid change and should be part of the script, a difference is not a valid change (should be skipped and protect the target) or a difference is actually a conflict which should be resolved manually.

These bring you the safety net in your CI automation process.

Disclaimer: I am the product manager at DBmaestro

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will look at this tool. Is it possible to integrate with jenkins? I want to  perform CI to trigger the application server with jenkins and create and execute the db scripts

Comment: @Jugi yes it has integration with Jenkins, IBM UrbanCode Deploy and a very simple API that you can integrate with any other CI tool